# In Delphi/Free Pascal: is ^ an operator or does it simply denote a pointer type?

Tags: delphi, pointers, pascal, dereference

In Delphi/Free Pascal: is ^ an operator or does it simply denote a pointer type?

#### Sample code

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
    P: ^Integer;

begin
    New(P);

    P^ := 20;
    writeln(P^); // How do I read this statement aloud? P is a pointer?

    Dispose(P);

    readln;
end
```

Comment: If you've used C or C++, you can translate ^ where you see it to basically the same thing as * except that ^ is postfix (written after) when used to dereference and before when used to declare a pointer to X, whereas C consistently you put the * before the thing it's dereferencing.   X^ == (*X).

Comment: `P^` reads [pointer] `P` dereferenced. Confer: `^T` reads reference to type `T`. First is for the expressions, but latter is for the declarations.

Comment: BTW.  The power operator in Delphi is not `^`.  You need to use `function Power(x, y)`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When `^` is used as part of a type (typically in a type or variable declaration) it means "pointer to".

Example:

```
type
  PInteger = ^Integer;
```

When `^` is used as a unary postfix operator, it means "dereference that pointer". So in this case it means "Print what `P` points to" or "Print the target of `P`".

Example:

```
var
  i: integer; 
  a: integer;     
  Pi: PInteger;
begin
  i:= 100;
  Pi:= @i;  <<--- Fill pointer to i with the address of i
  a:= Pi^;  <<--- Complicated way of writing (a:= i)
            <<--- Read: Let A be what the pointer_to_i points to
  Pi^:= 200;<<--- Complicated way of writing (i:= 200)
  writeln('i = '+IntToStr(i)+' and a = '+IntToStr(a));
```

Comment: thanks, I was thinking of prefix vs postfix... I'm just confused with the notation for some reason!

Comment: interestingly though if the pointer is a pointer to a record either R^.value or R.value is allowed (delphi 7 anyway)

Comment: @Dampsquid Yes, the `.` operator implicitly dereferences the pointer to the left, if necessary. Unlike c where there is both `.` and the dereferencing equivalent `->`. | And when you get to function pointers, the syntax gets really confusing since even the address-taking operator `@` can become optional.

Comment: thanks **again!!!*** 

like I said, I was confused because I couldn't find a single piece of documentation stating that it was even an operator! but now it makes sense. :>

Comment: @Dampsquid that's quite weird... the notation must not carry levels of indirection, which is really weird.

Comment: IMO, you are adding unnecessary complexities with *prefix* and *postfix*. This concept does not burden Pascal as language. @AdamScottRoan, re: membership operator `.`: Delphi does automatic dereferencing for pointers to structured types.

Comment: @user539484 pascal has both prefix(`@`,`+`,`-`) and postfix(`^`) operators. No idea what you mean.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, in Pascal, `^` is postfix-only.

Comment: @Johan, where did you see an operator there? Or expression? It is a declaration, duh!

Comment: CodeInChaos: the "." pointer derefence is specific to Delphi dialects. In normal Pascals (including Delphi predecessor Turbo Pascal) you need to dereference and select field: recordptrvar^.fieldname. In freepascal it depends on dialect mode.

Comment: Johan: as operator it is, type declaration (including casts) is a different story.